# File upload fail when in production on tomcat7

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2.1.1 with Scala and have a controller to deal with file uploads, specifically images. Locally this works perfectly, however, I have now deployed a war file using play2-war-plugin (https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) to a server running ubuntu and tomcat7.

Now when I upload an image I get the following exception

> [ScalaIOException: MainException: class java.io.IOException(No such
>   file or directory)]

My controller is

```
def addProjectImage(id: Long) = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    DB.withSession{ implicit session => {
        request.body.file("img").map { picture =>
            import java.io.File
            val filename = picture.filename + ".png"
            val contentType = picture.contentType
            var f = new File(s"./public/upload/project_picture/${filename}")
            picture.ref.moveTo(f)
            Projects.updateImage(id, "/assets/upload/project_picture/"+filename)
            Redirect(routes.Admin.index)
          }.getOrElse {
            Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
              "error" -> "Missing image"
            )
          }
    }}
}
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like a problem with the url to the file location. If you didn't encounter the problem locally but you did when using Tomcat, you should make sure that the url you are composing is correct. Can you access it using your browser?
In which line are you getting the IOException? Is it in `var f = new File(s"./p....`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the error is on that line. I can't access the file as it never uploaded. I can access files in that folder that I uploaded when testing locally. To access those files I only use "/assets/upload...." url because in routes I have `code`GET  /assets/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`code`